# Only get data with 56 as the 8th and 9th digits in SQL

Tags: sql

Working on an SQL query where data is only shown from phone numbers where the 8th digit is "5" and the 9th digit is "6."  For example, a phone number ending in "567."

Comment: Hi Brett and welcome to StackOverflow just thought I share this with you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Research `SUBSTRING()`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable where phone like '_______56%'
```

`_` stands for a single character
`'%'` stands for any number of character, including 0.

Comment: I modified it slightly to '______%56%_' and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: That ruins the whole point. If you want the 8-9th places to be 5,6 it must be preceded by 7 `_`. Your change makes it fetch every number with 56 from the 8th place or higher